# charging batteries

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charging

[image]

I need some advice, I have 8 older Gould 3ETC7 (6V) batteries 22.5 amp 8 hrs, they have completely discharges but were kept in a basement. I have 200 w of solar 12v, and a 3000w inverter to be used for emergencies and some non essential loads. Should I charge up each battery separately with a large battery charger or connect all together (2 in series to get 12v the parallel with the other 3 pairs) and charge with the solar gradually.

Comment: Looks ancient, don't blow yourself up.

Answer (score 2):

When lead-acid batteries are allowed stand for even a short time after being fully discharged they build up lead sulphate on their plates which prevents them from being charged, a process known as sulphation (or sulfation). The chances are your batteries are now permanently damaged. You could try charging one or two batteries to see if they can be charged. If you have a 6V charger try charging one. If you have a 12V charger try charging 2 connected in series.